# Re-Process mp4 video based on timestamps Python

Tags: python, video, time, timestamp, video-processing

I have a cool project where I have a .ttml file that has video subtitles and then I have the .mp4 video. [image: The image below has the timestamps].

What I am trying to do is to figure out how can I cut the video where it only displays the part of the video at the timestamps. So basically for each time stamp, I have to save that exact part in the video where that person says that.

**Getting the timestamps might not be too challenging the code below is does it, but How do I align these timestamps to save portions of my mp4 file??.**

```
  time_chunks = []
total_time = datetime.timedelta()
file_text = "".join(open(file_name).readlines())
p_tags = Selector(text=file_text).xpath("//p").getall()
for ptag in p_tags:
    begin = Selector(text=ptag).xpath("//@begin").get()
    endie = Selector(text=ptag).xpath("//@end").get()

    start_time = dt.strptime(begin, '%H:%M:%S.%f') - datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1)
    endie_time = dt.strptime(endie, '%H:%M:%S.%f') - datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1)

    total_time += endie_time-start_time
    time_chunks.append((start_time.total_seconds(), endie_time.total_seconds()))
```

I would appreciate any help I can get on this, code would be great I had too much theory for the day haha. Thanks

Comment: If you're looking to cut out a portion of the video [ffmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Main-options) is your friend. use "-ss" to specify start time and "-to" to specify end. So something like `ffmpeg -i my_video.mp4 -c copy -ss "00:00:10.323" -to "00:01:17.382" my_segment3.mp4`

Comment: Thanks Luke that works @Luke

Answer (score 1):

As Luke commented, you can use [FFmpeg](https://www.ffmpeg.org/).

You can use it as command line tool (execute it as external command using `subprocess`).
You can also use Python binding [ffmpeg-python](https://pypi.org/project/ffmpeg-python/).
I chose to use it as command line - under Windows, I put `ffmpeg.exe` in the working folder.

There are issues cutting a video file without re-encoding.
See: [Using ffmpeg to cut up video](https://superuser.com/questions/138331/using-ffmpeg-to-cut-up-video).
The issue is that without re-encoding you can cut the video only in **key frames**.

For simplicity, I generated an uncompressed AVI raw video file, for testing (all frames are like key frames).

Here is a working code sample:

```
import ffmpeg
import datetime
from datetime import datetime as dt
from scrapy.selector import Selector
import subprocess as sp

file_name = 'subs.ttml'

in_vid_file = 'vid.avi'

# Build synthetic video, for testing (uncompressed AVI file):
##############################################################
sp.Popen('ffmpeg -r 30 -y -f lavfi -i testsrc=size=192x108:duration=300:rate=1 -c:v rawvideo -pix_fmt bgr24 ' + in_vid_file).wait()
##############################################################

time_chunks = []
total_time = datetime.timedelta()
file_text = "".join(open(file_name).readlines())
p_tags = Selector(text=file_text).xpath("//p").getall()
for ptag in p_tags:
    begin = Selector(text=ptag).xpath("//@begin").get()
    endie = Selector(text=ptag).xpath("//@end").get()

    #start_time = dt.strptime(begin, '%H:%M:%S.%f') - datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1)
    #endie_time = dt.strptime(endie, '%H:%M:%S.%f') - datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1)

    #total_time += endie_time-start_time
    #time_chunks.append((start_time.total_seconds(), endie_time.total_seconds()))

    #Kepp the time in string format
    time_chunks.append((begin, endie))

# Iterate time_chunks
for t in time_chunks:
    beg_t = t[0]
    end_t = t[1]
    out_vid_file = 'vid_from_' + beg_t.replace(':', '_') + '___to___' + end_t.replace(':', '_') + '.avi'

    # https://superuser.com/questions/138331/using-ffmpeg-to-cut-up-video
    # Execute ffmpeg command in subprocess, and wait for finish.
    # Example: ffmpeg -y -i vid.avi -c copy -ss 00:00:00.030 -to 00:00:01.420 vid_from_00_00_00.030___to___00_00_01.420.avi
    sp.Popen('ffmpeg -y -i ' + in_vid_file + ' -c copy -ss ' + beg_t + ' -to ' + end_t + ' ' + out_vid_file).wait()
```

---

I used the following `subs.ttml` file for testing:

```
<p begin="00:00:00.030" end="00:00:01.420" style="s2">Due to the hustle and bustle of a sweet, floating city,</p>
<p begin="00:00:02.060" end="00:00:03.080" style="s2">Saying & ;It  never  relate me.</p>
<p begin="00:00:03.580" end="00:00:04.440" style="s2">The color of my heart is turning white</p>
<p begin="00:00:05.940" end="00:00:07.100" style="s2">But we can't do well, anyway</p>
<p begin="00:00:07.100" end="00:00:09.040" style="s2">So, cheers to your naughty smile.</p>
```

---

Result files:
`vid_from_00_00_00.030___to___00_00_01.420.avi`
`vid_from_00_00_00.030___to___00_00_01.420.avi`
`vid_from_00_00_03.580___to___00_00_04.440.avi`
`vid_from_00_00_05.940___to___00_00_07.100.avi`
`vid_from_00_00_07.100___to___00_00_09.040.avi`

---

I let you decide how to handle the re-encoding issue.
You can work hard, and find a way to cut at the time of the key frames and preserve video quality, or re-encode the video, to get precise time cutting, and loose some quality.